# Is it possible to get my domain back?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, domain-registrar

I've had a domain for about 10 years. It expired on 2017-02-18. I got emails about it. I tried to renew it, but I couldn't, because I can't open my account on a registrar's site. I wrote mails, but nobody answered. It's Erdomain.com.

Whois shows what a registrar is `PDR LTD. D/B/A PUBLICDOMAINREGISTRY.COM`. Also they updated registration till 2017-02-18. They didn't answer on my emails.

I don't know what to do...

Is it possible to get my domain back?

Comment: Call them on the phone. There is generally a 30 day grace period. Act fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found how to do it.

Erdomain's dashboard is available on http://erdomain.myorderbox.com. In the dashboard I moved my domain to another reseller.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on your hosting partner... But most likely your domain name will be used to show an advertisement page to profit from "existing" traffic.

The domain may also be auctioned to other people, or released so it can be registered again.